# Example on Electron of theia doesn't run

Tags: electron, theia

I am trying to run an electron example on theia. Getting following exception. Any help ?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-164-202-79:~/theia$ yarn run rebuild:electron
yarn run v1.9.4
$ theia rebuild:electron
Processing node-pty
Processing vscode-nsfw
Processing find-git-repositories
✔ Rebuild Complete
Done in 4.70s.
ubuntu@ip-10-164-202-79:~/theia$ cd examples/electron/
ubuntu@ip-10-164-202-79:~/theia/examples/electron$ yarn run start
yarn run v1.9.4
$ theia start
/home/ubuntu/theia/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Done in 1.39s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message shows that library llibXss is missing. You can install it by using

> sudo apt-get install libxss1